# Mount NFS Share In Windows On Non-Standard Port

Tags: linux, windows, nfs, port, mount

I have an NFS server on a Linux machine bound to a non-standard port. I can map it on another Linux machine using them command: `mount -v -o port=$PORT $IP:/ /$MOUNTPOINT`, but I can't seem to find any way to specify the port on the windows client. Is it possible to mount this share on windows?

Comment: There is no way to connect NFS shares with windows mount on other ports than NFS.